# Метод цепочек, HashMap

Tags: java

Как реализовать "метод цепочек"?

> Метод цепочек
>
> Разрешение коллизий при помощи цепочек. Каждая ячейка массива H
>   является указателем на связный список (цепочку) пар ключ-значение,
>   соответствующих одному и тому же хеш-значению ключа. Коллизии просто
>   приводят к тому, что появляются цепочки длиной более одного элемента.
>
> Операции поиска или удаления элемента требуют просмотра всех элементов
>   соответствующей ему цепочки, чтобы найти в ней элемент с заданным
>   ключом. Для добавления элемента нужно добавить элемент в конец или
>   начало соответствующего списка, и, в случае, если коэффициент
>   заполнения станет слишком велик, увеличить размер массива H и
>   перестроить таблицу.
>
> При предположении, что каждый элемент может попасть в любую позицию
>   таблицы H с равной вероятностью и независимо от того, куда попал любой
>   другой элемент, среднее время работы операции поиска элемента
>   составляет Θ(1 + α), где α — коэффициент заполнения таблицы.

```
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class hashmap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        hashmap.put("key1", "value1");

        hashmap.put("key1", "value2");

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вероятно вы хотите сделать свою реализацию `HashMap` в библиотечной `HashMap` уже и так все работает. Вот серия видео где подробно разбирается процесс создания простой `HashMap` во всех подробностях : [Создание HashMap часть 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka3_4vxMGjM&index=5&list=PL7Bt6mWpiiza-bvhK-O1dNjIITX7nReHk)

Comment: я хочу чтобы при добавлении записей с одинаковым ключом значения не перезаписывались а добавлялись в список этого ключа

Comment: @aaa для этого придется написать свой `HashMap` с библиотечным это не получится. Условие не добавлять одинаковые ключи зашито в глубине класса `HashMap`. Но это к стати не будет иметь ничего общего с разрешением коллизий о которых говориться в статье которую вы привели в вопросе. А тот метод о котором рассказывается у вас, и так уже реализован в `HashMap` только там речь идет о коллизиях которые как известно происходят не часто. Для этого надо чтобы для разных объектов был вычислен одинаковый `hashCode`. Решите что вы хотите дубликаты ключей хранить или коллизии разрешать, это разные вещи.

Comment: В самом начале этой статьи сказано что решение коллизий осуществляется с помощью метода цепочек https://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/

Comment: @aaa да так и есть. Просто решение коллизий путем добавления в цепочку, и просто добавление одинаковых значений в цепочку это не одно и то-же. В случае с коллизиями добавление происходит только если проверка метода `equals` дает `false` в то время как хэшкоды равны. Вообще что-бы разобраться как работают хэштаблицы надо сначала углубиться в устройство `equals()` и `hashCode()`. Так как вся логика хэштаблиц на них строится. Я поэтому вам в ответе и дал ссылку на серию видео, потому что пока не разберетесь с `equals()` и `hashCode()` все время будет не понятно.